# Get HTTP 403 but page is displayed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, http-headers, http-status-code-403

After analyzing the web, to see SEO failures, I see that I have a page that returns a 403 but it is shown as any other page.

The web is in Drupal, and I verified that it was not a block that was added with blocked permissions.

I do not see why it returns 403.

[image]

Comment: Is the page a node or a view page or custom menu?

Comment: @Chandraveer it's a node

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have 403 page configured under `/admin/config/system/site-information`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, only 404 page is configured, 403 page configuration is void